# C++ string's internal buffer address undefined behaviour

Tags: c++11

Is the following undefined behaviour under c++11 standard:

(trying to get the address of the internal buffer of a string)

```
std::string s;
... = &s[0];
```

for example when `s` is empty?

I know that we have `c_str(), data()`, but nevertheless.

### Note

this is coming from a debate with someone, this is not intended to promote hacky coding

Comment: You also have s.data()

Comment: @Alex yes, still the question remains

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11, the code is well-defined, but may not do what you expect. The exact effects are, as per 21.4.5/2:

> *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value
>   `charT()`; the referenced value shall not be modified.

So if the string is non-empty, it returns a reference to the internal buffer's start. If it's empty, it returns a reference to a `char` with value `0`, whose location is memory is an implementation details.

Comment: So, `&str[str.size()]` could always return a pointer to the same address for every `str`?  Meanwhile, `*(str.data()+str.size())` for non-empty strings is a `'\0'` adjacent to `&str.back()`?  Amusing.

Comment: @Yakk Um, not for every `str`. `c_str()` and `data()` returns a pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`. So for non-empty strings, `&str[str.size()]` must be the `'\0'` adjacent to `back()`.

Comment: @T.C. I think I see it now.  `data()+i` being in terms of `operator[](i)` implicitly forces `operator[]` to return contiguous elements, including `operator[](size())`.  That is also what forces `for(char& c:str)` to be contiguous characters?  No, that is covered (in the current standard proposal) by the contiguous iterators concept.  Contiguous iterators don't force the null terminator to be contiguous, however: that is the data clause?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, that's the `data()`, I believe. `string`'s iterators doesn't cover the null terminator, so the contiguous iterator rules doesn't apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you an address somewhere on your stack. Due to the small-string optimization in most implementations.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/ says:

> If pos is equal to the string length, the function returns a reference to the null character that follows the last character in the string, which shall not be modified.

You may get problems in form of undefined behavior as soon as your index-parameter is greater than the size of string.

Comment: cplusplus is non-normative, and disagrees with the standard in this case.

Comment: Well, that's a surprise to me! Thank you for pointing this one out. I think cplusplus refers to a specific implementation that has implemented this behavior!? It its not clear to me what charT() generates... may this be any value of type charT or does the standard somewhere states the value of  a default constructed charT()?